# Getting file not found error during xctest cases build

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, cocoalumberjack

I am facing compile time issue during unit test cases build. getting following error in one of my class file.[image]

we are  using xmppframework in project as pod dependency which inturn uses cocoa lumberjack . didnt get any issue while building other targets. problem is only with xctest cases only…

here is my pod file, adding xmppframework to both targets, but still issue persists…`target ‘MySdk' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'XMPPFramework', '~> 3.7.0'
 target 'MySdkTests' do

 inherit! :search_paths 
 end
end`

any help would be appreciated. i have been struck with this issue for past few days…

Comment: Did you run pod install after changing your podfile to include your test target?

Comment: yeah i ran pod install

Comment: @Avilam Share a sanitized version of your entire pod file. Do you have multiple targets?

Comment: i have already posted contents of pod file...i have only two targets

Comment: @Avilam try to clean the build and rebuild then just run the tests irrespective of the error and if the tests still fail then go to the report navigator tab and share the error log with us here

Comment: In file included from <built-in>:340:
<command line>:5:9: warning: 'SDK_VERSION' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SDK_VERSION @"3.1.4-beta3"
        ^
<command line>:3:9: note: previous definition is here
#define SDK_VERSION @"3.1.4-beta1"
        ^
In file included from /Users/Vinayak/Desktop/fix/mySdk/legacy/Reachability.m:14:
/Users/Vinayak/Desktop/fix/mySdk/mySdk/public/Logging.h:62:9: fatal error: 'CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h' file not found
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.

Comment: @staticVoidMan got above error